# How do I change a field description using hook_form_alter()?

Tags: 8, forms

I used to simply replace the string in the #description property, but now it isn't a string and I am not able to change it.

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form_id') {
    $form['field_myfield']['widget'][0]['value']['#description'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup::create(t('My custom description'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Today is  `$form['field_myfield']['widget'][0]['value']['#description'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup::create(t('My custom description'));`  (remove  `['value']`   )

Comment: Also add use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form_id') {
    $form['field_myfield']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#description'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup::create(t('Description'));
  }
}
```